# getting the contents of a page through node http request

Tags: json, node.js, http, steam

so I'm trying to get the contents of the following page:

http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198009923867/inventory/json/730/2

So I've got this code:

```
app.get('/inventory', function(req, res){
//send a web request to http://www.steamcommunity.com/profiles/<NUM>/inventory
var options = {
    host: 'www.steamcommunity.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/profiles/' + steamIDtoTrade + '/inventory/json/730/2/'
} 
http.get(options, function(http_res){
    var data = "";

    http_res.on("data", function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
    })

    http_res.on("end", function(){
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    })
})
```

});

But when I look at my response, this is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9u0W.png

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually just ended up doing it with the request library. Worked great!

```
app.get('/inventory', function(req, res){
  var steamID = req.query.steamID;
  //send a web request to http://www.steamcommunity.com/profiles/<NUM>/inventory
  request({
    uri: 'http://www.steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + steamID + '/inventory/json/730/2/'
  }, function(error, response, body){
    res.send(body);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

may be try adding `headers` in your `options`, as:

```
var options = {
    host: 'www.steamcommunity.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/profiles/' + steamIDtoTrade + '/inventory/json/730/2/',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work :(. If it does help, the content that I'm looking for is wrapped in an HTML <pre> tag. Maybe that has something to do with the distortion?

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that, when you request this link "http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198009923867/inventory/json/730/2", the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/ https://api.steampowered.com/ http://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com https://www.gstatic.com https://apis.google.com; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://steamcommunity.com http://steamcommunity.com https://api.steampowered.com/; frame-src 'self' http://store.steampowered.com/ https://store.steampowered.com/ http://www.youtube.com https://www.youtube.com https://www.google.com;
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Location: http://steamcommunity.com/id/QuickSkope/inventory/json/730/2
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 26
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 1414159326
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2015 07:25:19 GMT
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

So the real resoure path is "http://steamcommunity.com/id/QuickSkope/inventory/json/730/2".
You should know that the `http` module is a very simple module, it can handle this redirection case. So you can use this lib: https://github.com/olalonde/follow-redirects or [request](https://github.com/request/request).

The `request` can handle http redirect.

> Request is designed to be the simplest way possible to make http
>   calls. It supports HTTPS and follows redirects by default.

So you can use stream easily,

```
request.get("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198009923867/inventory/json/730/2").pipe(fs.createWriteStream("wy.txt"))
```